# codeigniter 3.0.4 hmvc not working for perticular module

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have got a peculiar problem in Codeigniter 3.0.4 when working with HMVC. My `Users.php` controller never working in LIVE server (Debian). Its working on local server (windows+xampp) in any combination.

[image]

## What I have tried so far is

In normal condition (like in image) its showing blank page

when lowercase the file name (`users.php`) then show 404 error

sometimes shwoing 500 error

some modules are working but users module not working (Only Live)

HMVC downloaded from here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads

Tried this too [HMVC codeigniter works on local server but not on web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527648/hmvc-codeigniter-works-on-local-server-but-not-on-web-server)

Comment: Check your file names it is case sensitive for Linux servers no problem with windows

Comment: Rename your file **Users.php** to **users.php**

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the file

> allication/config/routes.php
>   ??

I met the same question few days ago, and my solve steps are:

1. check the file : application/config/routes.php

   $route['default_controller'] = 'module_name';

   If the module_name is module1, this line must be

   $route['default_controller'] = 'module1';

   But if the module_name is Module1, this line must be

   $route['default_controller'] = 'Module1';

[routes and module_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdVb.png)

The module_name is case sensitive, you have to be sure the **directory name** have to be the same with the **$route setting**.

2. Add a MY_Controller.php in application/core directory

[MY_Controller.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/248vx.png)

3. check the directories structure : application/modules

   I have two modules named firstpage and Ref_Module

   the directory structure have to be like the fig of the step 1.

After the steps finished, I solve my question.